# Why do some subplots in matlab disappear?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am working with image processing using a Gabor filter to analyse textures, but I am facing a issue when trying to plot multiple images in a figure using `subplot`. I have tried to display an array of 2 x 5 figures. The code runs without any error, but only the bottom figures (second line) are presented. The top figures (first line) seem to disappear. Can anyone give me a hint how to tackle this problem?

Below I present the full code, but the problem is related to the second part (plot of the figures):

```
[nome,caminho] = uigetfile('*.*','File Selector');
im = imread(strcat(caminho,nome));

escala = 1;
im = imresize(im,2);

[x,y,z] = size(im);

figure(1);imshow(im);

imc = imcrop(im);

figure(1);imshow(im);title('Imagem de trabalho');impixelinfo;

wl = [2:2:10];
ori = [0:15:90];
gabor_array = gabor(wl,ori);
[mag,phase] = imgaborfilt(imc,gabor_array);

for i = 1:length(ori);
   figure(i);
   hold on
   for j = 1:length(wl);
        subplot(1,length(wl),j);
        imshow(mag(:,:,j),[]);
        subplot(2,length(wl),length(wl)+j)
        imshow(phase(:,:,j),[]);
   end
   hold off
   impixelinfo;linkaxes;
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try running your code line by line (eg using the debugger) to see if those images are actually displayed in the places you think they are?